# Mass Copying and Renaming Files with Batch

Tags: batch-file

to-be friends,

I want to write a code which does the following:
I have a file (.mp4) and I have a.txt with titles; one each line.
Now I want to create a .mp4 copy for each title in the .txt
So basically a copy of the original .mp4 should be made and then be renamed after title no.1
then another copy with title no.2 and so on.

So far I found out how to copy and rename files with an ascending number in the title:

```
C:\>for /L %f in (1,1,1000) do copy C:\Temp\1Filename.mp4 C:\Temp\%fFilename.txt
```

Comment: Good for you ! So what is the question ?

Comment: Oh, I thought it's obvious. I'm new here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line will do what you want

```
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %i IN (`type "C:\path\to\titles.txt"`) DO COPY "C:\Temp\OriginalFilename.mp4" "C:\Temp\%i.mp4"
```

Note that if you want to run that batch from a .bat file every `%i` has to be changed to `%%i`.

Comment: @user3314067 The biggest thanks is accepting the answer here on Stackoverflow by clicking the checkmark on the left on my answer :)